# Sony smartband swr10 app development

Tags: android, api, sdk, sony

Are there any API or SDK (for Android) to retrieve data **directly** from smartband swr10 bypassing *Lifelog* app ? I would add to my app, the ability to retrieve these data, store it on personal database and process them when needed.

If the answer is no, is it possible to connect this device with *Google Fit* app, synchronize data and then retrieve them from their cloud ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no APIs or SDKs available to directly access data from SWR10.  Google Fit APIs are supported for the SmartBand Talk SWR30 but not for SWR10.